# I'm trying to open a window in a certain size?

Tags: onclick

I am trying to get an image to open a window to a certain size when I click on it. The window has an audio player in it and I want the window size to be the size of the audio player. I want it to be responsive - but right now would settle for being able to get the window to resize to a certain size. Below is the code I am using on the image I am clicking on to open the "audio player window".

```
<a href="http://wizs.com/listen-now-test/"TARGET="_blank">
<IMG src="http://test.wizs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/9.png"></a> 

<a href="target.htm"
onclick="window.open('target.htm', 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no,
location=no, status=yes, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, width=300,
height=200'); return false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="http://wizs.com/listen-now-test/" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://wizs.com/listen-now-test/', 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=yes, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, width=300, height=200'); return false">
    <img src="http://test.wizs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/9.png">
</a>
```

There is no need for two distinct `<a>` tags. You may also want to disable the scrollbars in your popup window (`scrollbars=no`).

Comment: `code` <a href="http://wizs.com/listen-now-test/"TARGET="_blank">
<IMG src="http://test.wizs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/9.png"> 
<href="target.htm"
onclick="javascript:window.open('target.htm', 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no,
location=no, status=yes, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, width=150,
height=150'); return false"></a>

Did I merge the to <a> tags correctly? 
It's still not changing the size of the window... 
Thanks,

Comment: Not really; just use the code snippet I posted in my original answer.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the address bar?

Comment: `location=no` is the option for the address bar, but it is not supported by most of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding javascript: to the beginning of the onclick attribute like this:

```
onclick="javascript:window...."
```

Comment: I added the javascript: to the current code but may have done it wrong? 

`code` <a href="wizs.com/listen-now-test/"TARGET="_blank">; <IMG src="test.wizs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/9.png"></…; <a href="target.htm" onclick="javascript:window.open('target.htm', 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=yes, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, width=300, height=200'); return false">

It's still not changing the size of the window...